# When I isolate a test it passes, but when run sequentially with other tests it fails with NoSuchElementError

Tags: protractor

I was making some changes to the page objects we use for running our Protractor tests to run on Sauce Labs i.e., calling a utility method to get browser and platform so we can use the appropriate test user, and after making the change I kept getting a NoSuchElementError when running the test suite.

When I isolate the logout test, it passes, but when run in conjunction with any other files, it fails. Currently, I'm only running the login test and logout test on Chrome to limit the possible causes.

We use page objects to navigate to a testable state, in this case a login page object and a dashboard page object (logging in takes you to the dashboard).

The login page object:

```
'use strict';

var TestUtils = require('../../util/test-utils.js');
var HeaderPageElement = require('../page_elements/header-page-element.js');

var LoginPage = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.get = function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:9000/index.html');
        this.header = new HeaderPageElement();
        this.loginForm = element(by.name('loginForm'));
        this.usernameInput = element(by.model('credentials.username'));
        this.passwordInput = element(by.model('credentials.password'));
        this.loginButton = element(by.name('loginButton'));
        this.signupLink = element(by.xpath('//a[@ui-sref="signup"]'));
    };

    this.setCredentials = function (username, password) {
        var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
        var testUtils = new TestUtils();

        testUtils.getCapabilities().then(function (capabilities) {
            return testUtils.getTestUser(capabilities.browserName, capabilities.platform);
        }).then(function (testUser) {
            username = username || testUser.username;
            password = password || testUser.password;
            self.usernameInput.sendKeys(username);
            self.passwordInput.sendKeys(password);
            deferred.fulfill();
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.login = function (username, password) {
        return this.setCredentials(username, password).then(function () {
            return self.loginButton.click();
        });
    };

    this.signup = function () {
        return this.signupLink.click();
    };

    this.get();
};

module.exports = LoginPage;
```

The dashboard page object:

```
'use strict';

var LoginPage = require('./login-page.js');
var HeaderPageElement = require('../page_elements/header-page-element.js');
var ProjectCreateModalPageElement = require('../page_elements/project-create-modal-page-element.js');

var DashboardPage = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.get = function () {
        var loginPage = new LoginPage();
        loginPage.login();
        this.header = new HeaderPageElement();
        this.newProjectButton = element(by.name('newProjectButton'));
        this.projectFilterInput = element(by.name('projectFilterInput'));
    };

    this.createNewProject = function (projectTitle, projectTypes) {
        var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
        this.newProjectButton.click().then(function () {
            var modalPage = new ProjectCreateModalPageElement();
            modalPage.createNewProject(projectTitle, projectTypes);
            deferred.fulfill();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.get();
};

module.exports = DashboardPage;
```

These are the tests that are being run.

The login test:

```
'use strict';

var LoginPage = require('./pages/login-page.js');

describe('login test', function () {
    var page;

    beforeEach(function () {
        page = new LoginPage();
    });

    it('should be directed to login', function () {
        expect(page.loginForm.isPresent()).toBe(true);
    });

    it('Login button should be disabled', function () {
        expect(page.loginButton.getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual('true');
        page.setCredentials('wrong', 'user').then(function () {
            expect(page.loginButton.getAttribute('disabled')).toEqual(null);
        });
    });

    it('login should fail and remain at login screen', function () {
        page.login('wrong', 'user').then(function () {
            expect(page.loginForm.isPresent()).toBe(true);
        });
    });

    it('login success should redirect to dashboard', function () {
        page.login().then(function () {
            browser.wait(function () {
                return $('#dashboard').isPresent();
            });
            expect($('#dashboard').isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

The logout test:

```
'use strict';

var DashboardPage = require('./pages/dashboard-page.js');

describe('logout test', function () {
    var page;

    beforeEach(function () {
        page = new DashboardPage();
    });

    it('logout success should redirect to login page', function () {
        page.header.logout().then(function() {
            browser.wait(function () {
                return $('#login').isPresent();
            });
            expect($('#login').isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

The error I get when running these tests sequentially is as follows:

`NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.model("credentials.username")`

The line it specifies is the `get` method inside the DashboardPage object, whereby it instantiates a LoginPage object and calls the `login` method so as to navigate to the dashboard:

```
this.get = function () {
    var loginPage = new LoginPage();
    loginPage.login();
    this.header = new HeaderPageElement();
    this.newProjectButton = element(by.name('newProjectButton'));
    this.projectFilterInput = element(by.name('projectFilterInput'));
};
```

For whatever reason, the `usernameInput` of the login page hasn't been set by the time the `login` method is called.

I'm quite sure it's got something to do with not having coded promises correctly, but I've been bashing my head against it for days without any success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it just that you are still logged in because of the "login" test once you reach the "logout" test and try to log in? In other words, it looks like you are trying to log in when you are already logged in.

Comment: That is correct.  The problem was that we were developing using an in-memory database, and whenever the app was refreshed it went back to the login page.  The tests were constructed with that in mind, but in attempting to parallelise the tests we had to fix a login bug so that behaviour got nerfed and I completely forgot about it.  I undeleted this as a reminder of my stupidity.  I would give you points if it were possible.